# WPF how to set the datatemplates of a contentcontrol?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, navigation

I was pretty confused as to how the following code example works.  It seems like the Contentcontrol gets the datatemplate from the window resources.

Doesn't contentcontrol have its own "contenttemplate" that should determine what view is in it? Does it just search upwards and set its content to the datatemplate if nothing is set on it?

I may be mixing up the two terms, but I'm really confused as to why the example stores the datatemplate at the window resources level.

Regardless, I am trying to understand what options I have for setting the view for a given Window. Originally I was going to just use a contentcontrol and host the view inside it, but then I wondered if maybe there might be a reason to have the contentcontrol select a Page (from the actual page class) as opposed to a view (that extends user control).

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeViewModel}">
            <local:HomeView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductsViewModel}">
            <local:ProductsView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>


<DockPanel>
    <Border DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                            Command="{Binding DataContext.ChangePageCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"
                            Margin="2,5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because of the [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes.  If a DataTemplate specifies DataType (without a Key), then the runtime will match up objects of that type to the template.

> Doesn't contentcontrol have its own "contenttemplate" that should determine what view is in it?

It does, but if it does not have its `ContentTemplate` property set, then the runtime looks to apply a DataTemplate matching the type.  The MSDN documentation makes the analogy to `TargetType` on a `Style` element -- you can apply a style locally, but you can also apply a style globally to a certain type.  For example, using `<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">` applies that style to all buttons in the scope.  Likewise `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomeViewModel}">` applies that template to all content with the type "HomeViewModel".

> Does it just search upwards and set its content to the datatemplate if nothing is set on it?

Sort of, yes.  It searches the current resources, which includes resource keys inherited from parent resource dictionaries.

> I may be mixing up the two terms, but I'm really confused as to why the example stores the datatemplate at the window resources level.

It doesn't really matter -- you could store them at the application level, or even inside the `ContentControl`.